# Stanford NLP - NER - Train NER with names that have multiple tokens

Tags: c#, nlp, stanford-nlp

I have recently started taking a look at Stanford NLP (using the C# port). 
I have planned on using NER to identify store location names and product names - to do this i will need to train the tagger, which i am in the process of doing.

However, some locations for example "Kings Cross" should only really be considered a location when both tokens are together. i.e i wouldn't want "Kings" getting tagged as a location when it is used by itself in a sentence.

So my question really is: Is there a defined way that it is recommended that I deal with locations/names that have a space in them (both in my training files, and in code)?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Your two options are to train a statistical tagging algorithm and hope it does the correct thing, or to use the `regexner` annotator and supply it with a list of known named entities.  In your list of known named entities for instance, you can include an entry for `Kings Cross` and it will only work if it sees the full phrase `Kings Cross`.

More documentation for `regexner` is available here:

https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/regexner.html

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of dealing with this in NER is using IOB tags [or some variation](https://web.archive.org/web/20170805150451/https://lingpipe-blog.com/2009/10/14/coding-chunkers-as-taggers-io-bio-bmewo-and-bmewo/). Labels using IOB could look like this:

```
I        O
went     O
to       O
Kings    B-PLACE
Cross    I-PLACE
```

Where `O` means "no label", `B-XXX` means "beginning of XXX", and `I-XXX` means "in XXX".

The tagging system will learn multi-word tokens start with a `B` and sometimes continue with `I` tokens; it's just another tag transition. To collect multiword tokens from tagger output you just walk through, create an entry for any `B`, and append the `I`s to it.